# Custom height with scroll on a dropdown

Tags: flutter

So I have a dropdown widget but when the list increases the dropdown increases. How can I avoid this? I for e.g I want to make it 400 height max and have a scroll inside. Also is it possible to add a placeholder instead of adding a value as first selected?

[image]

```dart
child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                        dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                        isExpanded: true,
                        value: dropdownValue,
                        focusColor: Colors.white,
                        items: [
                          'Country',
                          'B',
                          'C',
                          'D',
                          'E',
                          'A',
                          'B',
                          'C',
                          'D',
                          'E'
                        ].map((String value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: value, child: Text(value));
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (_) {}),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`menuMaxHeight:400`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/menuMaxHeight.html) to set Custom height.

```dart
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
  child: DropdownButton(
    menuMaxHeight: 400,
```

Comment: Possible to add placeholder? Like default value but I want it not to be selectable

Comment: in that case, you can use nullable value like `String? dropdownValue;` you can also check `hint` property to show something before selection